# Unable to parse xml in windows Phone universal app

Tags: c#, xml-parsing, win-universal-app

I have below XML which i want to parse but i am not able to parse. i have checked all possibilities which i can check.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<toast>

  <visual>

    <binding template="ToastText01">

      <text id="1">Test message</text>

      <text id="section">TRS</text>

    </binding>

  </visual>

</toast>
```

I tried to parse root elemeny but receiving null value

```
 string  xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?> <toast > <visual> <binding template = \"ToastText01\" ><text id = \"1\" > Test message </text > <text id = \"section\"> tias-request-show </text> </binding ></visual> </toast> ";

    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
            XElement value = xdoc.Root.Element("toast");
```

Comment: what is issue, why i am not getting any node

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
 XElement value = xdoc.Element("toast");
```

There is no need to access Root to get hold of the `toast`-node.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out

xdoc.Document.Element("toast");